# iphone popup custom size in IB

Tags: iphone, uiview, popup, size

In my application I need show some info popup. This is just a text message above an image. When I create UIView for my popup in IB, it's size is non-ediatable (and equals to 320x460).
But my popup is not full-screen size.
Of course, I can create this popup programmatically, but I'd prefer data-driven approach.
So, the question is: how do I create custom-size UIView in IB?

Comment: Create a XIB file (not using Xcode), add it to your project and you can resize the view to what ever you like. Then just add it as a subview and make sure you hook up a way of removing it. If you use core animation, you can make it show/hide all fancy-like!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set status bar of the view to none then you should be able to resize the view.

Answer (score 0):

When a view is at the root level in an interface builder document it will always appear to be 320x460 but the size isn't actually set. Interface builder is just simulating what it will look like when it's actually loaded.

If this Popup view is actually supposed to appear in another existing view then drag it inside that view in IB. Once it's no longer at the root level you will be able to set its size.